# How to store current datetime data in Redis Server

Tags: redis

I would like to store data like this in Redis #SET datetime:1 "Login time [date] and in hour is [current time]"

How to replace the content in brackets?
As we know in SQL we can use getdate() function, but how in Redis?

Answer (score 2):

There is [TIME](https://redis.io/commands/time) command, but it won't work if you simply pass it as a parameter to SET. You can either to do it programatically in whatever language you are using. Or with a Lua script using [EVAL](https://redis.io/commands/eval) command.

Comment: Note that TIME is a non deterministic command, and as such will cause a Lua script to err upon attenpting a write. You can overcome that, in v3.2 and above, by turning on effects replication instead of the default scripts replication.